# How do I use apache2gdl with XAMPP on Windows 7?

Tags: perl, apache, xampp

This is a question for all Apache/Perl gurus out there. Is it possible to try out [Apache2GDL](http://www.aisee.com/apache2gdl/) on XAMPP in a Windows 7 environment? If so, what are the steps?

So far I have put the `apache2gdl.pl` file in my cgi-bin directory, but how do I run the script on Windows 7? This is how they want you to run it:

```
> cat <log file> | apache2gdl.pl [URL pattern] > <graph file>
```

log file is `/logs/access.log` and URL is `localhost` and graph file is `graph.gdl`, I guess. I'm a total noob on this so please bear with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take it out of the `cgi-bin` directory, the program is not a CGI program. Run it from the command prompt.

---

No wonder you are confused, the instructions on their site are terrible. This is the result of absent-minded documentation efforts, lack of a style guide, not bothering to take great documentation as a role model and learning from it.

```
> cat <log file> | apache2gdl.pl [URL pattern] > <graph file>
```

The first `>` indicates the shell prompt. You are not supposed to type that.

The pairs of `<…>` indicate a placeholder. It is a bad idea to use them because they conflict with the other uses I mention immediately above and below. They should have been using `[…]` all along, or better using a different typographic convention which has no chance at all to cause conflict through multiple possible ways to read.

The last (single) `>` is a piece of real shell syntax. Its meaning is to redirect the output from the `apache2gdl.pl` program into a file.

---

Eliminating the useless use of `cat`, I would write the synopsis this way, once with abstract placeholders and once with concrete example data:

> perl apache2gdl.pl *URL_PATTERN* < *LOG_FILE* > *GRAPH_FILE*
>
> perl apache2gdl.pl example.com/foo/bar < /logs/access.log > graph.gdl